# Error when I try to map(persist) my database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'am trying to map my database(jira database) using JPA/Hibernate.
but an error occure when I do that!!(I have tried the same configuration on another database and it's worked)
My cofiguration files:

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JIRAKPIPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Portalpage</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzFiredTriggers</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Jiraworkflows</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Externalgadget</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.OsHistorystepPrev</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Versioncontrol</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdApplicationAddress</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Oauthspconsumer</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Label</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertydata</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.ExternalEntities</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Changeitem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Upgradehistory</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Favouriteassociations</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Jiraaction</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuestatus</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Priority</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Serviceconfig</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzJobDetails</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Permissionscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Userhistoryitem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Oauthconsumertoken</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzJobListeners</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldlayoutscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Jiraeventtype</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Genericconfiguration</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Searchrequest</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Configurationcontext</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Changegroup</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Customfieldoption</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Customfield</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.OsCurrentstepPrev</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Userassociation</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Remembermetoken</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Userbase</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldconfigscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Jiraissue</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdDirectoryOperation</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuetypescreenscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Gadgetuserpreference</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Filtersubscription</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Optionconfiguration</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Projectroleactor</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldscreen</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertydate</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Oauthsptoken</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzCronTriggers</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Schemeissuesecuritylevels</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Upgradeversionhistory</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Projectversion</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdDirectory</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldscreenlayoutitem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldscreenschemeitem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Notificationscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuelinktype</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.OsWfentry</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldscreenscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Notification</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuesecurityscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Schemeissuesecurities</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Jiradraftworkflows</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdApplication</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Jiraperms</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzSimpleTriggers</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldscreentab</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzTriggers</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Component</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuelink</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Trustedapp</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fileattachment</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertydecimal</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertystring</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Avatar</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Project</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdUser</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Membershipbase</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdDirectoryAttribute</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Workflowschemeentity</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Notificationinstance</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldconfigschemeissuetype</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Schemepermissions</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Projectrole</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuetype</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Columnlayoutitem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Groupbase</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Columnlayout</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Mailserver</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Sharepermissions</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertyentry</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Oauthconsumer</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdMembership</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.SequenceValueItem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.TrackbackPing</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldlayout</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Customfieldvalue</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertynumber</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Workflowscheme</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Listenerconfig</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzTriggerListeners</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Portletconfiguration</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Projectcategory</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldlayoutitem</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Pluginversion</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.OsHistorystep</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdGroup</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdGroupAttributes</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldlayoutschemeassociation</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Issuetypescreenschemeentity</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldconfiguration</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Fieldlayoutschemeentity</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Propertytext</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.OsCurrentstep</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Resolution</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.QrtzCalendars</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Worklog</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.Nodeassociation</class>
        <class>DTOJIRA.CwdUserAttributes</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jiradb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

**hibernate.cfg.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jiradb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**My class Read:**

```
public class JiraissueRead {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("JIRAKPIPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public JiraissueRead() {
    }

    public Jiraissue findKpi(Integer id) {
        System.out.println("ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt");

        try {

            EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
            System.out.println("debut 1");
            entr.begin();
            entr.commit();
            System.out.println("debut 2");
            Jiraissue j = em.find(Jiraissue.class, id);
            return j;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MAin:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JiraissueRead jiraissue = new JiraissueRead();
    System.out.println("_______________");
    System.out.println(jiraissue.findKpi(10000));

}
```

**The error**

```
17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findById => SELECT c FROM CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.id = :id
17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByUserId => SELECT c FROM   CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.userId = :userId
17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByDirectoryId => SELECT c FROM    CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.directoryId = :directoryId
17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByAttributeName => SELECT c FROM CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.attributeName = :attributeName
 17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
 INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByAttributeValue => SELECT c FROM   CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.attributeValue = :attributeValue
 17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
 INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByLowerAttributeValue => SELECT c FROM CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.lowerAttributeValue = :lowerAttributeValue
 17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
 INFO: Bind entity DTOJIRA.CwdUserAttributes on table cwd_user_attributes
 17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
 INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
  17 juin 2011 17:39:12 org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider configure
 ATTENTION: No connection properties specified - the user must supply JDBC connections
 Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: J  IRAKPIPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory  (HibernatePersistence.java:126)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:51)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
at DAOJIRA.JiraissueRead.<init>(JiraissueRead.java:16)
at DAOJIRA.Main.main(Main.java:18)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:57)
at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory   (AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
... 5 more
Java Result: 1
```

After I have added the hibernate.dialect to my persistence.xml and the error changed,know the error is(the error it's too long):

```
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findAll => SELECT n FROM Nodeassociation n
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findBySourceNodeId => SELECT n FROM     Nodeassociation n WHERE n.nodeassociationPK.sourceNodeId = :sourceNodeId
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findBySourceNodeEntity => SELECT n FROM      Nodeassociation n WHERE n.nodeassociationPK.sourceNodeEntity = :sourceNodeEntity
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findBySinkNodeId => SELECT n FROM Nodeassociation n WHERE n.nodeassociationPK.sinkNodeId = :sinkNodeId
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findBySinkNodeEntity => SELECT n FROM    Nodeassociation n WHERE n.nodeassociationPK.sinkNodeEntity = :sinkNodeEntity
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findByAssociationType => SELECT n FROM Nodeassociation n WHERE n.nodeassociationPK.associationType = :associationType
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Nodeassociation.findBySequence => SELECT n FROM   Nodeassociation n WHERE n.sequence = :sequence
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity DTOJIRA.Nodeassociation on table nodeassociation
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: DTOJIRA.CwdUserAttributes
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findAll => SELECT c FROM CwdUserAttributes c
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findById => SELECT c FROM CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.id = :id
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByUserId => SELECT c FROM  CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.userId = :userId
 18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByDirectoryId => SELECT c FROM    CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.directoryId = :directoryId
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByAttributeName => SELECT c FROM  CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.attributeName = :attributeName
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByAttributeValue => SELECT c FROM    CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.attributeValue = :attributeValue
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: CwdUserAttributes.findByLowerAttributeValue => SELECT c FROM CwdUserAttributes c WHERE c.lowerAttributeValue = :lowerAttributeValue
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity DTOJIRA.CwdUserAttributes on table cwd_user_attributes
18 juin 2011 09:49:46 org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider configure
ATTENTION: No connection properties specified - the user must supply JDBC connections
juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory       buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory  getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or    transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Scrollable result sets: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query cache: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider
INFO: Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Statistics: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
18 juin 2011 09:49:47 org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
 _______________
 ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
debut 1
The user must supply a JDBC connection
errrrrs
++++++++++null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

The dialect to be used by Hibernate EntityManager when used as the JPA provider, can be configured as a property in the persistence.xml file as:

```
<persistence-unit>
  <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      ...
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Configuring Hibernate for use as a JPA 2.0 provider.**

Going by the [Hibernate EntityManager](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration) documentation, one does not need the `hibernate-cfg.xml` file in an environment where JPA is used. All properties may be specified in the `persistence.xml` file, and these can also include properties that are native to Hibernate.

Comment: Hello,thank you for the reply. I have added the hibernate.dialect to my persistence.xml and the error changed,know the error is:     ATTENTION: No connection properties specified the user   must supply JDBC connections
    org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory    buildTransactionFactory
      org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
    INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
___The user must supply a JDBC connection
errs
++null

Comment: @rym, I'd like to take a look at the update persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml files.

Comment: @rym, I don't see why you should have a hibernate-cfg.xml and a persistence.xml file at the same time. Like I've stated in the answer, you can configure the hibernate.dialect property in the persistence.xml file, the property name in use is not from the "javax.persistence.*" space, so it will be picked up if applicable. I think it should be safe to do away with the hibernate-cfg.xml file, for it does not serve any purpose.